# Get the proportion of the variance explained in a plsda with recipes

Tags: r, tidymodels, r-recipes, pls

I try to compute the proportion of the variance explained by each component in a PLSDA, using the `tidymodels` framework.

Here's the "gold standard" result with the `mixOmics` package:

```r
library(mixOmics)

mix_plsda <- plsda(X = iris[-5], Y = iris$Species, ncomp = 4)

mix_var_expl <- mix_plsda$prop_expl_var$X
mix_var_expl
#>       comp1       comp2       comp3       comp4 
#> 0.729028323 0.227891235 0.037817718 0.005262724
sum(mix_var_expl) # check
#> [1] 1
```

And here with `recipes::step_pls()`:

```r
library(recipes)
tidy_plsda <-
  recipe(Species ~ ., data = iris) %>% 
  step_pls(all_numeric_predictors(), outcome = "Species", num_comp = 4) %>% 
  prep()

tidy_sd <- tidy_plsda$steps[[1]]$res$sd
tidy_sd
#> [1] 0.8280661 0.4358663 1.7652982 0.7622377
tidy_sd ^2 / sum(tidy_sd^2)
#> [1] 0.14994532 0.04154411 0.68145793 0.12705264
```

The element that looks like the most to an explained variance is `sd`, but as you can see, there is no obvious relationship between these two vectors.

How can I get `mix_var_expl` from `tidy_plsda`? Thanks!

<sup>Created on 2022-09-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recipe object does not save the mixOmics model; just the parts that we need to process new data. The `sd` object is the standard deviations of the predictors. There is no current way to get what you want from the object.

I've added a GitHub issue to add more objects to the results though: https://github.com/tidymodels/recipes/issues/1038